# QR Code error while split the string

Tags: android, exception, split, qr-code

Am using zxing integration code to scan the qr code in my android project. am getting the result in string like  **CMD#9874563210**. now want to split and get into two string.

i have tried the following function to split the string,

```
public void populateScanData(String scanData){

    /*StringTokenizer strTkn = new StringTokenizer(scanData, "#");
    ArrayList<String> arrLis = new ArrayList<String>(scanData.length());
    while(strTkn.hasMoreTokens())
        arrLis.add(strTkn.nextToken());
    String merCode = arrLis.toArray(new String[0]).toString();
    String mobileNo = arrLis.toArray(new String[1]).toString();*/

    String string = scanData;
    String[] parts = string.split("#");
    String part1 = parts[0]; // 004
    String part2 = parts[1]; // 034556

    // Set to the credit acc field
    txtCreditAcc.setText(part2);

    // Set to the redemption merchant name
    lblRedMerName.setText(part1);

}
```

but upon doing am getting the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=180446, result=0, data=null} to activity
```

here my code for scannin qr code

```
/**
 * Function to start the scan
 * @param view - The view object calling the function
 */
public void startScan(View view) {

    // Create the scanIntegrator
    IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);

    // Start the integrator
    scanIntegrator.initiateScan();

    // Start the integrator
    AlertDialog alertDialog=scanIntegrator.initiateScan();

    if(alertDialog==null) {

        // Disable the credit account field
        txtCreditAcc.setEnabled(false);

        // disable the amount button
        txtPayAmount.setEnabled(false);

        //disable the reference button
        txtPayReference.setEnabled(false);

        //disable the debit account layout
        layDebitAccount.setEnabled(false);

    }

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    // Store the scanning result
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    // Check if the result is null,
    if (scanningResult != null) {

        // get the scan content
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();

        populateScanData(scanContent);


    } else {


        generalMethods.showToastMessage(context,"No scan data received!");

    }

    //Enable the credit account field
    txtCreditAcc.setEnabled(true);

    // Enable the amount button
    txtPayAmount.setEnabled(true);

    //Enable the reference button
    txtPayReference.setEnabled(true);

    //Enable the debit account layout
    layDebitAccount.setEnabled(true);

}
```

please help me, so long am fed on this. thanks.!